# Using Addthis share in iFrame but using Parent URL

Tags: share, facebook-social-plugins, addthis, social-media

How can I get the parent URL for Addthis Share widget? When the Addthis code is inside an iFrame.

At the moment when I click share it gets the iFrame URL not the parent URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to programmatically obtain the parent URL, but you can manually set the URL to be shared by adding the data-url attribute to the AddThis code (or addthis:url if using legacy (pre-dashboard) sharing buttons).

http://www.addthis.com/academy/setting-the-url-title-to-share/